# CORS issues after upgrading to .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I had an .NET Core 2.1 application which handled CORS well. But after upgrading to 2.2 I faced the problem:

[image: google chrome]

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://content.xxxx/user/avatar' from origin 'https://cabinet.xxxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Response Headers: (might this be an issue with IIS?)

> Connection: close
>
> Content-Length: 315
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
>
> Date: Tue, 22 Jan 2019 15:08:26 GMT
>
> Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

I tried every combination I could find here (enabling CORS before and after MVC, adding and removing UseCors from Configure method), but nothing worked.

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       ...
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://cabinet.xxxxxx")
                                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                                  .AllowCredentials()
                                  .AllowAnyHeader());
        });


        services.AddMvc();
        ...
    }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseHsts();
        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
```

and the method is

```
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
    [Route("user/avatar")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task Method(IFormFile file) {...}
```

Am I missing something? I don't want to downgrade back to 2.1.

Comment: The screenshot explains the problem *and* how to fix it. CORS *is* enabled and complains about an attempt to access a *third-party URL*. The header that says it's OK to call `content....../user/avatar` is missing.

Comment: Well, I don't quite get it. I tried 'AllowAnyOrigin()' but it didn't help too. Or do you mean that I should change my call to 'content' server? I only do backend, should I change call and add specific header to it?

Comment: BTW post the error message itself, not pictures of the error message. Googling for the header name and `.net core` would return relevant answers. Right now I'd have to type it by hand just to search for samples

Comment: Instead of trying to turn off CORS you should check how to properly configure it. You are looking for a way to put the `content...` URL in that header. And I still have to type it by hand before I can search for samples

Comment: Checking [Enable CORS with CORS Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#enable-cors-with-cors-middleware) it looks like you tried the *second* option, which is used to specify multiple policies in `AddCors` and pick the one to actually use at runtime with `UseCors(policyName)`. Do you actually want this or could you use the first option, ie specify the policy in `UseCors()` ?

Comment: I want to apply '[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]' on exactly one method, but at this point I just want it to work. I did it with 2.1 and it worked, but after .net core 2.2 this error came back.

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I fail to reproduce this issue under .net core 2.2. And I only could reproduce by append extra `/` after `https://localhost:xx` like `https://localhost:xx/`

Comment: The thing is that even if I change `WithOrigin("https://cabinet.xxxx)` to `AllowAnyOrigin()` I still would have the same error.

Comment: No doubt this is a serious problem with ASP.NET Core 2.2. The worksaround works in some stages in others not; big problem in deployments. A nightmare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was an issue with IIS configuration. Moving website to another port helped.